# How to show quick look of a document in a splitview based iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, quicklook

I have to show quick look of a document in the detailView of a splitview based app. In the master view I have a UITableView with the list of all the files in the Document folder of my app.
 I'm trying to use the QLPreviewController in the DetailViewController, in this way:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = ...;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
[previewController release];
```

I'm able to see the preview of the document, but I don't longer see the toolbar at the top of the detail view, and in portrait mode I'm stuck forever, because I'm not able to see the file list in the master view. 
I also tried to make DetailViewController subclass of QLPreviewController, but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.<br>
But I want show it in the detail view of the split view, not in a modal view.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of pushing the previewController into the [self navigationController], what I believe you need to do instead, from what you described, is to set the previewController as the detail view of your UISplitViewController.

This can be done like so

```
[splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterViewController, previewController, nil]];
```

If you want to have the navigation bar for for the previewController to appear, you can wrap the previewController with a UINavigationController before setting it as the detail view in UISplitViewController like so:

```
UINavigationController *wrapperNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:previewController] autorelease];
[splitViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterViewController, wrapperNavigationController, nil]];
```

Cheers